# Calculate a trig function with an input and output in degrees

Tags: java, math, cross-product

I'm trying to make a calculator for some calc homework, but the information is given in degrees and the answer must be in degrees. I tried using the Math.toDegrees and Math.toRadians but the answer isn't correct.

```
public static double crossProduct() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter angle in degrees");
    double angle = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("x1 = ");
    double x1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("y1 = ");
    double y1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("z1 = ");
    double z1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("x2 = ");
    double x2 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("y2 = ");
    double y2 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("z2 = ");
    double z2 = in.nextDouble();

    double mag1 = Math.sqrt((x1 * x1) + (y1 * y1) + (z1 * z1));
    double mag2 = Math.sqrt((x2 * x2) + (y2 * y2) + (z2 * z2));

    double res = mag1 * mag2 * Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));      

    System.out.println("cross product = " + res);
    return res;
}
```

inputting <0,2,0> and <0,5,0> and angle = 90 degrees should give the answer as 10. instead it returns:

572.9577951308232

Any ideas?

EDIT: Also, if anyone has a better/shorter way for inputting the components, that would be amazing.

Comment: Why do you transform sin return value to degrees?

Comment: Because the answers must be in degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossproduct is a number that is not expressed in degrees. You need to convert the angle to radians before passing it to `Math.sin`, but converting the result back to degrees is incorrect.

```
double res = mag1 * mag2 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

Comment: @yazan Angles are measured in degrees, radians, gradians, [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Units). Cross product, on the other hand, is not an angle, so it is not measured in angular units. You should not convert a number that does not represent an angle to any angular units, because the result would make no sense.